# How do I transform an array of dimensions (100, 1) into 2 separate arrays in C#?

Tags: c#, arrays

I have an array where if it's laid out visually consists of 100 rows and 2 columns, or (99,1).  What I'd like to do is create 2 one-dimensional arrays such that (0-99,0) is in 1 array, and (0-99,1) is in another array.  How do I do this in C#?  Here's my code that's almost there but not quite.

```
   //Create Arrays A and B for the 2 columns of arrData

        string sourceFilePath = @"c:\data.txt";
        var arrData = File.ReadLines(sourceFilePath).Select(line => line.Split('\t')).ToArray(); 


        string[] arrA = new string[arrData.Length]; 
        string[] arrB = new string[arrData.Length]; 

        long lngCounter;

        for (lngCounter = 0; lngCounter <= arrData.Length; lngCounter++)
        {
            arrA[lngCounter] = arrData[lngCounter,0];
            arrB[lngCounter] = arrData[lngCounter,1];
        }
```

Comment: It's called a for loop. Kind of like linq, but you can do more stuff with it.

Comment: Is the source a multi-dim or a jagged array? Always provide code.

Comment: Ok, I hear you SO.  I included my code that should've come with the question.

Comment: Show declaration of arrData please.

Comment: So we have an array of an array => jagged array. Do you only have 2 columns in your text file?

Comment: I thought it's only jagged if the arrays in each "row" have a different number of elements.  Here, in my data, I know for sure that each row of data will always have 2 columns of data.

Comment: your resulting array of lines consists of arrays-of-columns (caused by the Split method). The difficulty is that these internal arrays can have any length. Its a special case that you always have 2 values in the text file. But that doesnt matter.

Comment: Note that you are looping to far in the for loop above: `lngCounter <= arrData.Length`; use `<` instead.

Comment: I can't see the problem in your code. What kind of difficulties do you have?

Comment: Henk, now I'm confused.  Can you please elaborate on the difference between arrData.Length and arrData.GetLength(0)?

Comment: GetLength(0) and Length is the same. GetLength can be used to access lengths of ranks > 0. GetLength is used on rectangular arrays.

Comment: Ok, GetLength is used on rectangular arrays...but didn't we just establish that the array here isn't rectangular?  So would my use of arrData.Length be perfectly okay here?

Comment: Thats the point. Henk maybe not uptodate with our findings or likes to use GetLength(0). Length is totally valid in your case.

Comment: Yes, sorry. I assumed multi-dim (string[,]) and it's actually an array-of-array (string[][]). So just Length is OK. Note that the use of `var` obscures this a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easy fix:

```
            for (lngCounter = 0; lngCounter < arrData.Length; lngCounter++)
            {
                arrA[lngCounter] = arrData[lngCounter][0];
                arrB[lngCounter] = arrData[lngCounter][1];
            }
```

Remember the output of the array creation is not a rectangular but a jagged array. You assumed rectangular.

I want also add that the code will break as soon as there are less than 2 columns in the textfile. So be aware of it.

Comment: Thank you BlueM for recognizing and solving my problem!  Also, thank you for the heads up about potential breakage.  I consider myself forewarned!

Answer (score 1):

Homework?

Here's one way to split a rectangular array with [at least] 2 columns into 2 1-d arrays:

```
private static void Split<T>( T[,] src , out T[] col1 , out T[] col2 )
{
  int  rows = src.GetLength(0) ;

  if ( src.GetLength(1) < 2 ) throw new ArgumentException("src") ;

  col1 = new T[ src.GetLength(0) ] ;
  col2 = new T[ src.GetLength(0) ] ;

  for( int i = 0 ; i < rows ; ++i )
  {
    col1[i] = src[i,0] ;
    col2[i] = src[i,1] ;
  }

  return ;
}
```

Comment: I'm sure this won't work on his arrData. His array creation doesn't produce a rectangular array.

Answer (score 1):

A few less lines, though pretty much the same as the accepted answer

```
    string[][] jaggedString = new string[3][];

    jaggedString[0] = new[] {"test", "test1"};
    jaggedString[1] = new[] {"free", "free1"};
    jaggedString[2] = new[] {"done", "done1"};

    var array1 = jaggedString.Select(c => c[0]).ToArray();
    var array2 = jaggedString.Select(c => c[1]).ToArray();
```

two lines:

```
var array1 = arrData.Select(c => c[0]).ToArray();
var array2 = arrData.Select(c => c[1]).ToArray();
```

Comment: +1 for using Select. The most elegant solution to his problem.

Comment: I'm intrigued...so no For loop is necessary?  Will using this Select solution shave time off total computation time?

Comment: It will not do any magic. Basically its the same as what you wrote but as two liner ;-)

Comment: I doubt you'd see any performance differences, especially on 100 rows

Comment: actually, running a few tests the for loop crushed the select on 1 million rows in the file, though it was all under a second